# How to import XML into Access via XSLT transform and create as many tables as needed?

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, import

I have this endless XML file and I'm trying to import it into MS Access 2016.
Inside XML I have many tags called "parameter" with a name in a "name" tag and inside each "parameter" I have a list of products with products ids (named "articles") and its properties.

What I need to achieve after import is to have as many tables in my MS Access database as I have "parameter" tags in my XML file.
Each table name should be taken from corresponding "name" tag of the "parameter".
In each table I want to have a column with all the products ("articles") and a column with all values.

For example first Table should be named "Body", it should have a first column 'article' with three items: 012968, 013123 and 014137. And second column 'property' should have three values: Steel, Rubber, Steel.

How can I import it this way?

Here is a sample of the XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <parameters>
    <parameter>
      <id>6</id>
      <name>Body</name>
      <unit/>
      <type>text</type>
      <multiple>0</multiple>
      <modified>13.10.2022 13:57:21</modified>
      <marking/>
      <descript/>
      <category>F7F28766D524D347AC3514F12BDD8C00</category>
      <select>
        <option value="Steel">Steel</option>
        <option value="Rubber">Rubber</option>
      </select>
      <ranges/>
      <products>
        <product article="012968" param_order="11">
          <values>
            <value order="0" text="Steel">Steel</value>
          </values>
        </product>
        <product article="013123" param_order="15">
          <values>
            <value order="0" text="Rubber">Rubber</value>
          </values>
        </product>
        <product article="014137" param_order="11">
          <values>
            <value order="0" text="Steel">Steel</value>
          </values>
        </product>
      </products>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <id>23</id>
      <name>Count</name>
      <unit>nm</unit>
      <type>number</type>
      <multiple>0</multiple>
      <modified>13.10.2022 13:44:07</modified>
      <marking/>
      <descript/>
      <category>F7F28766D524D347AC3514F12BDD8C00</category>
      <select/>
      <ranges/>
      <products>
        <product article="005181" param_order="2">
          <values>
            <value order="0" number="1">1 pc</value>
          </values>
        </product>
        <product article="005327" param_order="2">
          <values>
            <value order="0" number="1">1 pc</value>
          </values>
        </product>
        <product article="012672" param_order="3">
          <values>
            <value order="0" number="15">15 pc</value>
          </values>
        </product>
      </products>
    </parameter>
    </parameters>
</data>
```

I've tried to create XSLT transform file but as far as I can get is to create a good import only if I delete everything from my XML file except for a one set of products from only one "parameter". And repeat the process hundreds of times (as much as I have "parameters" in my XML file). A great pile of manual work duh.

This is my XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <table>
         <xsl:for-each select="//product">
            <Body>
               <article><xsl:value-of select="@article"/></article>
               <number><xsl:value-of select="values/value"/></number>
            </Body>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result of the import should be:

```
First Table "Body"

Columns:
"Article" "Property"

Values:
012968    Steel
013123    Rubber
014137    Steel

Second Table "Count"

etc..
```

And so on.

Also here is the random XML file with right XML format which MS Access can happily swallow (for those who don't work with MS Access):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot>
    <NOTARIO>
        <C_NOT>8404180</C_NOT>
        <APE>Abalos Nuevo</APE>
        <NOM>Francisco José</NOM>
        <NOTARIA>
            <C_NOT>8404180</C_NOT>
            <PRO>23</PRO>
            <MUN>0888</MUN>
            <F_IN>1984-12-01</F_IN>
            <F_FI>1986-09-19</F_FI>
        </NOTARIA>
        <NOTARIA>
            <C_NOT>8404180</C_NOT>
            <PRO>14</PRO>
            <MUN>0569</MUN>
            <F_IN>1990-09-17</F_IN>
            <F_FI>1995-03-15</F_FI>
        </NOTARIA>
        <NOTARIA>
            <C_NOT>8404180</C_NOT>
            <PRO>21</PRO>
            <MUN>0412</MUN>
            <F_IN>1995-03-30</F_IN>
            <F_FI />
        </NOTARIA>
    </NOTARIO>
</dataroot>
```

Comment: There is no such thing as an *endless XML file*.  Moreover, you're expected to produce the code for which you have a question -- a [mcve] illustrating the problem.  Please read [ask].

Comment: @kjhughes, thanks for your comment. Ok, maybe it's a bit of exaggeration but I have a really large XML here, I posted only a bit. Also I edited the post and added my XSLT.

Comment: Post what you wish the output to be given the input you show.

Comment: @loarrin I take it that MS Access has an XML format which it can import, and you want to transform your source XML so that it conforms to that format. It will really help if you show us a simple example document in that format which Access is happy to import, because the XSLT experts here are generally not also Access users.

Comment: Before you waste you time doing thing  wrong. Do them right.  First design your database that consider how to import.  Start by using an excel workbook and make each sheet a table for you database and the columns the properties of each table.  The xml you posted doesn't agree with your instructions.  It make no sense to have a separate table for each parameter in the xml.

Comment: Appreciate your help, thank you! @kjhughes, I edited my post and added the desired output.

Comment: @Conal Tuohy, nice idea, I will try to figure it out. For now It's a black box for me since it converts and transforms xml on the fly and I can see only the results as a "sql" tables. Upd: found, added to question.

Comment: @jdweng, you are right, the design looks a little ridiculous, but I have the old import process in MS Access and it worked quite well until this endless XML file came lol.

Comment: Please post the **exact XML result** you expect to get from you example input.

Comment: P.S. IMHO you should put all your products in the same table and relate them to a parent table of parameters. But that's a matter of DB design, not XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257km, finally I did it, thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need an import method.  Everything can be done in Powershell very easily.  Here is the xml import function

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"

$inDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$ident = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><dataroot></dataroot>'
$outDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($ident)
$dataroot = $outDoc.Root

$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$parameters = $inDoc.Descendants("parameter")

foreach($parameter in $parameters)
{
   $name = $parameter.Element("name").Value;
   $xName = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($name))
   $dataroot.Add($xName)
   $products = $parameter.Descendants("product")
   foreach($product in $products)
   {
      $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName name -NotePropertyValue $name
      $article = $product.Attribute("article").Value
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Article -NotePropertyValue $article
      $property = $product.Descendants("value")[0].Value
      $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Property -NotePropertyValue $property
      $table.Add($newRow) | Out-Null

      
   }
}
$outDoc.Save($outputfilename)
$table | Format-Table
```

Here is the results

```
name  Article Property
----  ------- --------
Body  012968  Steel
Body  013123  Rubber
Body  014137  Steel
Count 005181  1 pc
Count 005327  1 pc
Count 012672  15 pc
```

You just need code to put above table into multiple tables in Access.
I started to create a new output XML with format that access will accept, but not sure the format with the xml you provided.

Comment: let me thank you for your help! I have never seen such approach with converting XML via Powershell before but it turns out to be very handy. I was able to tune your script a bit to export results to XML and import them to MS Access. It's not what I expected since all data is in one table but I can agree that it's a better approach, I'll modify rest of my import process to always use one table for the import. Thanks again and have a nice day ;)